# Call AlpineJS function from javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a modal that i show or hide using alpine js.
When I press a button I check a bool and if it's true then I want to close that modal, to do so I have to interact with Alpines' data.
Is there a way to call Alphines' functions from JS?

I've tried using custom event but that doesn't seem to work

`let event = new CustomEvent("closeModal", {}); window.dispatchEvent(event)`

Then in the modals' div
`x-show="isOpen()" @closeModal.window="close"`

EDIT:
Thanks to pthomson answer I was able to make it work and I also found a way without using events

```
<div x-data>
    <button type="button" @click="$store.modal.open()">Open Modal</button>
    <div x-show="$store.modal.isOpen()">
        //Modal content
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => { 
        Alpine.store('modal', {
            show:false,
            isOpen() {
                return this.show;
            },
            open(){
                this.show=true;
            },
            close(){
                this.show =false;
            }
        })
    })

    function closeModal(){
        Alpine.store("modal").close();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this with an Alpine Store value and a custom event (on the `document`, but it would also bubble up to `window` if you want). The `alpine:init` event is registering the two document listeners.
Your button would dispatch this `closemodal` event (escape keydown also hides the modal in this example).
I have `style="display: none"` on the div to keep it hidden before `alpine:init` is called during page load... maybe an `x-cloak` on the div would achieve the same desired (initially hidden) effect.
NOTE: I include this single modal partial on all pages that need modal functionality. So it ends up being a single Alpine Store variable that all pages share, since they all share the same modal partial view in the page markup.

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
            Alpine.store('openmodal', false);

        document.addEventListener('openmodal', () => {
           Alpine.store('openmodal', true);
        })
        document.addEventListener('closemodal', () => {
           Alpine.store('openmodal', false);
           // clear modal content here if you want
        })
    });
</script>

<div
        x-show="$store.openmodal"
        style="display: none"
        x-on:keydown.escape.prevent.stop="$dispatch('closemodal');"
        role="dialog"
        aria-modal="true"
        class="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto"
    >
.. modal content
</div>
```

then somewhere else you have your button

```
<button onclick="$dispatch('closemodal');">close</button>
```

EDIT: based on your feedback, there are other ways to achieve what you are trying to do... not sure how your isOpen() function is getting the proper value to return, but your div can just listen for that button to raise the custom closemodal event.. for instance calling your isOpen function and passing in the state, but you get the idea? `<div x-on:closemodal.window="isOpen(false)">` basically the opposite of what you asked for: alpine listen for call from javascript.

Comment: Thanks, this is working but I don't really like using events this way so I'll try to see if I can find other way but still thanks!